# Call component function from a JS File

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I want to know If I can do this in react, I want to call a function or method of a react component from a JS file, so I could change the state of that component.

I have these three files for example

First App.js

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Login from './Login';

class App extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {session:false}
    }

    changeStateSession(state_session){
        this.setState({session:state_session});
    }

    render(){
        return(
            this.state.session
            ?<div>Content</div>
            :<Login/>
        );
    }
}
```

Login.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Auth from './Auth.js';



class Login extends Component{
    constructor(){
         super();
    }

    login(){
        Auth.login();
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <button onClick={(e)=>login(e)}></button>
        );
    }
}
```

And Auth.js

```
import App from './../../App.js';


const Auth = {
    login:App.changeStateSession(true)
};

export default Auth;
```

What I really want to know is if theres a way that I could call the App function (changeStateSession) from the Auth.js file, the Auth.js file is just an example of what I would like to achieve I know this file doesn't work, but I would like to know If there is a way to achieve something like this in react, hope you can help me , thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The more common way of doing something like this would be to pass your `changeSessionState` function as a prop to the `Login` component.

App.js:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { session: false }

        this.changeStateSession = this.changeStateSession.bind(this);
    }

    changeStateSession(stateSession){
        this.setState({ session: stateSession });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            this.state.session
                ? <div>Content</div>
                : <Login onSuccess={() => this.changeStateSession(true)} />
        );
    }
}
```

Login.js:

```
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    login(){
        // If your login process is asynchronous
        // and returns a Promise, for example
        Auth.login()
            .then(this.props.onSuccess);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={(e)=> this.login(e)}></button>
        );
    }
}
```

Now, when `this.props.onSuccess` is called once your login succeeds, your `App` component's state will be updated since your `changeStateSession` method was passed as a prop to your `Login` component.

The big takeaway here is that if you want to update a parent's state from a child component, passing functions from your parent component to the child component is the way to typically handle it. No other way of updating parent state from a child is recommended.

Also, if there is an absolute necessity to call the `changeStateSession` function from your `Auth.js` file, then it's a very similar concept. Just pass the function through and call it there instead.

Comment: so... the correct way is to put the Auth js logic inside the App component?, I came from the angular environment and I'm still attached to services and factories and all those things, so I would like to know what is the correct way to sepearate and ordedered your logic and files for give them support in react, thanks for your answer, In fact parent to child its the only way Ive found out to do this kind of action in react, and thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user3384672 It's perfectly reasonable to keep the logic of logging in (for example, calling an external service to authenticate the user) in a separate file. After all, React is really just a view layer. You can then call the login functionality from a component, and update the calling component's state based on the result of the service call. Put another way, your view layer (React) _should_ care that a user is authenticated (to display a username, etc.), but shouldn't really care _how_ you authenticate your user. Thus why it makes sense to keep that logic in a separate file as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use props. Either calling passing the function to a child component or just passing the value to the App component as a prop and calling the function in the parent component